# Why doesn't the process substitution <() work with ssh -F

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, file-descriptors, process-substitution

I have some vagrant virtual machines. To log into them I issue the `vagrant ssh` command. I want to log into them using regular `ssh` command. The `vagrant ssh-config` outputs the suitable config file

```
$ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2201
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/cbliard/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

When outputing this config in a file and using with `ssh -F`, everything works fine:

```
$ vagrant ssh-config > /tmp/config
$ ssh -F /tmp/config default
=> logged successfully
```

When using process substitution operator `<(cmd)` to prevent the creation of the temporary config file, it fails:

```
$ ssh -F <(vagrant ssh-config) default
Can't open user config file /proc/self/fd/11: No such file or directory
```

Same error happens when using `<(cat /tmp/config)`

```
$ ssh -F <(cat /tmp/config) default
Can't open user config file /proc/self/fd/11: No such file or directory
```

I am using zsh and I observe the same behavior with bash. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like ssh is closing all unexpected file descriptors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command:

```
ssh -F <(vagrant ssh-config) default
```

runs the `vagrant` command in a separate process with its stdout connected to a pipe. The other end of the pipe is connected as file descriptor `n` (in your case it's 11) to a new process that runs `ssh` and the shell runs:

```
ssh -F /proc/self/fd/n default
```

Now, that only works if `ssh` doesn't close its file descriptors on startup.

Unfortunately, it does.

If using `zsh`, an alternative is to use the `=(...)` form of process substitution where instead of using a pipe and `/proc/self/fd`, it uses a temp file.

Or you could use a file descriptor that `ssh` doesn't close. For instance, if you're not feeding anything to `ssh` (if the remote command is not reading anything from stdin) you could use `fd` 0, e.g.:

```
vagrant ssh-config | ssh -F /dev/stdin -n default
```

Comment: Wonderful. With `=(...)` it works like a charm and the temporary file is automatically removed when the `ssh` session ends. The variant with `/dev/stdin` connects successfully but exits immediately.

Comment: @cbliard, yes, if the command you run on the other end is an interactive shell, it will read from its stdin (which is the now used up pipe to vagrant) see the eof and exit. That's why I was saying _if you're not feeding anything to `ssh`_.

Comment: Ok, I did not understand what you meant with _if you're not feeding anything to `ssh`_. It is now clear.

Comment: Is this still true? I am successfully using: `ssh -F <(cat ~/.ssh/config ~/.ssh/hosts)` to join 2 config files together when running SSH. And on ZSH, I can do this: `ssh -F <(vagrant ssh-config) default`.

Answer (score 1):

based on @cbliard

This works:

```
ssh -F =(vagrant ssh-config ) -i =(generate ssh-identity)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify what `=( )` does? I'm not familiar with it.