# How to invoke `nix-shell` with the contents of an URL (e.g., a raw GitHub link)?

Tags: shell, nix

Saving it to file, and using that temporary file works fine,

```
$ url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/toraritte/shell.nixes/main/deno-latest-shell.nix"

$ curl $url > default.nix

$ nix-shell
# or
$ nix-shell default.nix
```

but how can one do this without using a temporary file? Here's what I tried so far:

#### Pipe

```
$ curl $url | nix-shell -
```

This downloads the file and the ... just nothing happens.

```
$ curl $url | nix-shell
```

This will throw an error that there is no `default.nix` (of course).

#### Process substitution

Using [the `<()` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703243/what-is-the-name-for-operator-in-bash) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210403191230/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703243/what-is-the-name-for-operator-in-bash)):

```
$ nix-shell <(curl $url)

# ... output...
error: getting status of '/dev/fd/pipe:[11284302]': No such file or directory
```

But when I change `nix-shell` to `cat`, it works, just as if I had saved the `curl` output into a regular file, and printed its contents.

(Maybe hitting the same issue with this approach that is explained in [Why doesn't the process substitution <() work with ssh -F](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101900/why-doesnt-the-process-substitution-work-with-ssh-f)? The solution there was using zsh with its special `=(...)` operator, that basically uses a temporary file behind the scenes.)

---

I know there is `nix-shell -E`, but it would probably be problematic even if my specific example Nix expression didn't contain comments...

Comment: Discussion: https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-invoke-nix-shell-with-the-contents-of-an-url-e-g-a-raw-github-link/12281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Nix bug, here is a similar one for [`nix eval`](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2734).

Until it is fixed, you can use `nix-shell -E "$(curl $url)"`. Or just using Nix, `nix-shell -E "import (builtins.fetchurl $url)"`.

Just please make sure you can trust the expression before executing it – the expression’s `shellHook` can contain arbitrary bash code and nix-shell will run it.

Comment: The second form of `nix-shell -E` works like a charm! I originally dismissed the first form of `nix-shell -E` because my `shell.nix` is heavily commented, but I was obviously just limited in my thinking. Thank you also for linking to [the `NixOS/nix` issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2734)! Haven't open a new issue for this, but updated it with this one for now.